# Java Spring Azure Function throws Initialized context: catalog=null, IllegalStateException: No function defined with name

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot, azure-functions

I have a Java azure function with spring boot integration. For some reason, the application throws errors when it tries to find the defined spring function:

This is the function `EventHubTriggerFunction.java`:

```java
public class EventHubTriggerFunction extends AzureSpringBootRequestHandler<String, String> {

    @FunctionName("messageRouter")
    public void run(
            @BindingName("SystemProperties") Map<String, Object> systemProperties,
            @BindingName("Properties") Map<String, Object> properties,
            @EventHubTrigger(name = "message", eventHubName = "eventhubName", connection = "conn", consumerGroup = "$Default", cardinality = Cardinality.ONE) String message,
            final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        String s = handleRequest(message, context);
        context.getLogger().info(s);

    }
}
```

This is my spring boot `Application.java`:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  @Bean
  public Function<String, String> messageRouter() {
    return value -> "HELLO FROM SPRING";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

The error, if a message is getting processed:

```
2020-11-25T09:53:01.320 [Information] Initialized context: catalog=null
2020-11-25T09:53:01.355 [Error] Executed 'Functions.messageRouter' (Failed, Id=8c680fe7-a275-4038-83d1-7ba7acb65129, Duration=129ms)Result: FailureException: IllegalStateException: No function defined with name=messageRouter
```

The function itself is triggering + processing until `handleRequest()` is getting called. This code is based in the example [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/master/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-azure) (including POM).

Comment: Though bean name by default takes method name, but can you try explicitly setting `@Bean(name = "messageRouter")`?

Comment: @krishg Sadly, this is also not working

Comment: It's strange. It works for me (without specifying Bean name as your original code snippet) when I used the [pom.xml from the example](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/master/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-azure/pom.xml).